# IPhone Development - sqlite3_bind_int not working

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i'm trying to insert some data on a database using this code:

```
-(void)insertLocationOnDatabase:(LocationType *)aLocation {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int location = [aLocation.locationID intValue];
    NSLog(@"Location ID: %i", location);
    const char *sql = "insert into tbl_location values (?,?,?,?)";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 0, location);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [aLocation.Description UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [aLocation.isActive UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [aLocation.sequenceOrder UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Location %@ inserted on database",aLocation.Description);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error on step: %i",sqlite3_errcode(database));
            }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error on prepare: %i",sqlite3_errcode(database));
    }
}
```

the problem is on line:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 0, location);
```

without this line and changing the sql, the code works fine, but when i put this line back, i get this error:

```
2010-09-17 10:24:01.032 StockControl[944:207] Error on step: 20
```

From sqlite3.h:

```
#define SQLITE_MISMATCH    20   /* Data type mismatch */
```

Somebody knows where is my mistake?

Regards,
Claudio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the docs for the [binding methods in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_bind_blob), the bindings count from one, not zero:

> The second argument is the index of
>   the SQL parameter to be set. The
>   leftmost SQL parameter has an index of
>   1.

That might well lead to a type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use following methods?

```
NSString *sqlCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                   @"insert into tbl_location values (%d,'%@','%@','%@')",
                  location, 
                  aLocation.Description, 
                  aLocation.isActive, 
                  aLocation.sequenceOrder];

const char *sql = [sqlCmd UTF8String];

// ...
```

I use bind only for large data, for example an image file.